# Click function on dynamically created table

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table and it created dynamically.When  i click the image then i need to remove the table row.In here click function is not working.

Dynamically created table.

```
row.append($("<td id="imageclose"><p>" + '<img src="' + '/Content/Images/crossimg.png' + '"  width:"225px" height:"225px" />' + "</p></td>"));
```

Click Function

```
$("#imgclose").click(function () {
    alert("asdfg");
});
```

Comment: You have to use delegated events. Try with `$(document).on('click', '#imgclose', function(){ alert('asdfg'); });`. Check out this link: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use class `imageclose` instead of `id` like following. Because `id` should be unique for each element.

```
row.append($("<td class="imageclose"><p>" + '<img src="' + '/Content/Images/crossimg.png' + '"  width:"225px" height:"225px" />' + "</p></td>"));
```

You need event [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically generated element.

```
$('body').on('click', '.imgclose img', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use of 'ID' because it should be unique. So instead of using ID use of class to fulfil your task.

**First Way**  with `onclick` calling function.

```
row.append($("<td><p>" + '<img src="' + '/Content/Images/crossimg.png' + '"  width:"225px" height:"225px" onclick="abc()" />' + "</p></td>"));

function abc() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

**Second way** with class attribute.

```
row.append($("<td><p>" + '<img class="myclass" src="' + '/Content/Images/crossimg.png' + '"  width:"225px" height:"225px" />' + "</p></td>"));

$('#tableId').on('click', '.myclass', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```